# Foreach only showing First item in array

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get data for each id using foreach. But when code run it get only data for 1 ID.. Following is the code

```php
$buffalidforavgmilk = Buffalodata::groupBy('buffaloID')->get('buffaloID')- >pluck('buffaloID')->toArray();
                            
foreach ($buffalidforavgmilk as $id) {
    $milkperid = Buffalomilkrecord::where('buffaloID', $id)->pluck('buffaloID')->toArray();
    dd([$buffalidforavgmilk,$milkperid]);
}
```

Output

```
      array:2 [▼
               0 => array:4 [▼
                             0 => "Buffalo-01"
                             1 => "Buffalo-02"
                             2 => "Buffalo-03"
                             3 => "Buffalo-04"
                            ]

               1 => array:5 [▼
                             0 => "Buffalo-01"
                             1 => "Buffalo-01"
                             2 => "Buffalo-01"
                             3 => "Buffalo-01"
                             4 => "Buffalo-01"
                            ]
            ]
```

Here Loop giving only 1 ID where as required array for all 4 ID
( for Test, i try to get only buffaloID)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dd` interrupts execution. If you wanted to dump every result and then stop execution, you should have used `dump` instead

```
foreach ($buffalidforavgmilk as $id) {
    $milkperid = Buffalomilkrecord::where('buffaloID', $id)->pluck('buffaloID')->toArray();
    dump([$buffalidforavgmilk,$milkperid]);
}

dd('Done');
```

This is not ideal though. You are making a query in each iteration of the loop.

One way you could remove the foreach is to change your query to use `whereIn`.

```php
$buffalidforavgmilk = Buffalodata::groupBy('buffaloID')->pluck('buffaloID')->toArray();

$milkperids = Buffalomilkrecord::whereIn('buffaloID', $buffalidforavgmilk)->pluck('buffaloID')->toArray();
```

Comment: You should show to to solve the select n + 1 problem too.

Comment: Thank You. I am new self learner so stuck at such basic concepts...